# nginx and gunicorn for a django project

Tags: django, nginx

Hello all am new to django and all its goodies ill like to know how to set up something like this with nginx and gunicorn for a django project thanks

virtual host1

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName project1.com
ServerAlias www.project1.com
ServerAdmin info@project1.com

Alias /static/ /path/to/project1/project1/static/
Alias /media/ /path/to/project1/project1/media/

ErrorLog   /path/to/project1/error.log
CustomLog /path/to/project1/access.log combined

WSGIDaemonProcess project1.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/path/to/project1:/path/to/project1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup project1.com

WsgiScriptAlias / /path/to/project1/project1/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/project1/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

virtual host 2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName project2.com
ServerAlias www.project2.com
ServerAdmin info@project2.com

Alias /static/ /path/to/project2/project2/static/
Alias /media/ /path/to/project2/project2/media/

ErrorLog   /path/to/project2/error.log
CustomLog /path/to/project2/access.log combined

WSGIDaemonProcess project2.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/path/to/project2:/path/to/project2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup project2.com

WsgiScriptAlias / /path/to/project2/project2/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/project2/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi William - welcome to Stack Overflow. What's not working with the setup you posted? What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: its working fine but i want to use nginx and  gunicorn.

Comment: Oh - I see. Have a read of http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/, and see how you get on.

Comment: i looked at this example and set just one site up but wen i go to my url i get ngnix default when i go to my ip i see my site

Comment: dominice can u write the answer so i can accept it as i followed the link and it works fine though i did had to read some more documetation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/ - that should be enough to get you started with nginx and gunicorn.